# Line height incorrect for paragraph containing span with smaller font size

Tags: html, css, typography, froala

I have a problem with the `line-height` style in paragraphs filled with a `span`, when the font size in the `span` is smaller than that of the paragraph.

My Angular application has an editable `div` element, and I use the [Froala editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) API commands to allow formatting. I added my own custom commands to modify the `line-height` in paragraphs.

The CSS sets a default font size and line height for the editor:

```
div {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-spacing: 1.25;
}
```

The initial markup is something like this:

```
<div>
  <p>Some long text that wraps here...</p>
  <p>Some long text that wraps here...</p>
  <p>Some long text that wraps here...</p>
</div>
```

After setting the font size and line height with the editor, the markup becomes:

```
<div>
  <p style="line-height: 1;"><span>Some long text that wraps here...</span></p>
  <p style="line-height: 1;"><span style="font-size: 8px;">Some long text that wraps here...</span></p>
  <p style="line-height: 1;"><span style="font-size: 40px;">Some long text that wraps here...</span></p>
</div>
```

As long as the font size in the `span` is equal or larger than the font size of the paragraph (in the present case, `20px`), the line height scales correctly. However, when the font size in the `span` is smaller than that of its paragraph, the line height does not scale as it should. The problem can be seen in **[this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/a1rv5z69/)**.

If I set `display: inline-block` on the `span` elements, the line height scales properly but that display setting messes up the wrapping in the editor. Otherwise, the only workaround that I can think of is to use data binding to set the line height with pixel units, after retrieving the font size inside of the paragraph. Is there a simpler way to force the line height to adjust to `span` elements with a smaller font size?

Comment: inline elements take the line height of their parent, if you want it to have it's own line height, use inline-block - [from w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading): On a non-replaced inline element, 'line-height' specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.

Comment: @Pete - But the line height of the parent takes the larger font size of the span into account, as you can see in [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/a1rv5z69/). I wonder why it does not when the font size in the span is smaller (and when there is nothing else in the paragraph).

Comment: because spans are inline so the line height you set on it is different than the one you set on the p - when you go bigger with the span, it increases the p's line height as the p has to adjust it's line boxes height to accomodate the larger text, when it goes smaller, the p doesn't have to do anything so it keeps it's original line height

Comment: this is logical behavior but a bit difficult to explain ... there is a kind of min/max involved here as you said, will try to get you the relevant Spec for this

Comment: check this : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced ...

Answer (score 0):

Use this fiddle to understand the answer in depth -
https://jsfiddle.net/gbrn58jd/

It shows how we decrease the font size span or by giving any class to modified span and keeping that in a block.

```
<div>
    <h3>
        Default font size: 20px, Line spacing: OK
    </h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>
    <hr/>
    <h3>
        Font size: 8px, Line spacing: Too large
    </h3>
    <p><span class="class1">Aenean ut orci vel massa suscipit pulvinar.</span></p>
    <hr/>
    <h3>
        Font size: 32px, Line spacing: OK
    </h3>
    <p><span class="class2">Nulla sollicitudin. </span></p>
    <hr/>
    <h3>
        Font size: 48px, Line spacing: OK
    </h3>
    <p><span class="class3">Nulla sollicitudin. </span></p>
</div>
```

Cheers,
Gaurav